# How to check subscription status when not using Observable.create()?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Say you have some long running task wrapped by an observable:

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return longRunningTask();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to check whether the observable has been unsubscribed to determine if we should cancel the work and bail out?

More specifically, is it possible to check the status of a subscription (e.g. `isUnsubscribed()`) when using `Observable.defer()` or `Observable.fromCallable()`?

I'm aware that you can check `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` when using `Observable.create()`, however, since it's ill-advised to use `Observable.create()`, how can this be done with other operators?

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Observable.doOnSubscribe(Action0)` and `Observable.doOnUnsubscribe(Action0)`. You can count the subscriptions and when there are none you can stop the job.

Greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The `fromCallable` doesn't expose the consumer. For this, you need `create` with a body such as the following:

```
final SingleDelayedProducer<T> singleDelayedProducer = 
    new  SingleDelayedProducer<T>(subscriber);

subscriber.setProducer(singleDelayedProducer);

try {
    T result;

    // computation

    if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }

    // more computation

    result = ...

    singleDelayedProducer.setValue(result);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Exceptions.throwOrReport(t, subscriber);
}
```

Comment: So you're saying there isn't a way to check the subscription state when using `fromCallable` or `defer`?

Comment: They were not designed for that in mind and such requirement rarely comes up.